# Как измерить производительность Node js парсера?

Tags: node.js, cpu

Необходим инструмент для анализа производительности и потребляемых ресурсов парсера для выявления пиков потребления памяти, нагрузки на цп и тд.

Натыкаюсь на инфу по бенчмаркингу http серверов, но у меня потоковый процесс, интересна статистика с течением времени